# Query to count records within time range SQL or Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, timestamp

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Row,TimeStamp,ID
1,2014-01-01 06:01:01,5
2,2014-01-01 06:00:03,5
3,2014-01-01 06:02:00,5
4,2014-01-01 06:02:39,5
```

What I want to do is count the number of records for each ID, however I don't want to count records if a subsequent TimeStamp is within 30 seconds.

So in my above example the total count for ID 5 would be 3, because it wouldn't count Row 2 because it is within 30 seconds of the last timestamp.

I am building a Microsoft Access application, and currently using a Query, so this query can either be an Access query or a SQL query. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query below does what you want however I don't understand your expected output. It returns a count of 4 (all the rows in your example) which I believe would be correct because all of your records are at least 30 seconds apart. No single timestamp has a subsequent timestamp within 30 seconds from it (in time).

Row 2 with a timestamp of '2014-01-01 06:00:03' is not within 30 seconds of any timestamp coming after. The closest is row #1 which is 58 seconds later (58 is greater than 30 so I don't know why you think it should be excluded (given what you said you wanted in your explanation)).

Rows 1/3/4 of your example data also are not within 30 seconds of each other.

This is a test of the sql below but like I said it returns all 4 rows (change to a count if you want the count, I brought back the rows to illustrate):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d727/20/0

Now check this example with some added data: (I added a fifth row)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aee67/1/0

```
insert into tbl values ('2014-01-01 06:01:01',5);
insert into tbl values ('2014-01-01 06:00:03',5);
insert into tbl values ('2014-01-01 06:02:00',5);
insert into tbl values ('2014-01-01 06:02:39',5);
insert into tbl values ('2014-01-01 06:02:30',5);
```

Note how the query result shows only 3 rows. That is because the row I added (#5) is within 30 seconds of row #3, so #3 is excluded. Row #5 also gets excluded because row #4 is 9 seconds (<=30) later than it. Row #4 does come back because no subsequent timestamp is within 30 seconds (there are no subsequent timestamps at all).

Query to get the detail:

```
select *
  from tbl t
 where not exists
 (select 1
          from tbl x
         where x.id = t.id
           and x.timestamp > t.timestamp
           and datediff(second, t.timestamp, x.timestamp) <= 30)
```

Query to get the count by ID:

```
select id, count(*)
  from tbl t
 where not exists
 (select 1
          from tbl x
         where x.id = t.id
           and x.timestamp > t.timestamp
           and datediff(second, t.timestamp, x.timestamp) <= 30)
group by id
```

Comment: So the reason for all of this is for use at a Walk-a-thon to count laps. I am planning on having someone enter ID numbers into my application as the walkers go by (possibly with a barcode scanner or multiple somehow), but the reason I want this query is in case the same person is entered or scanned twice in the same lap (which I figured 30 seconds would be good. Does that make sense? Sorry I think my original data example may have been misleading.

Comment: So my example should have had row 2 time of 06:01:03, thus this value gets dropped. It looks like your query does exactly what I want. Thank you.

Comment: How would I turn this into a count query?

Comment: @user3513237 For the count use the 2nd query, it should group by ID. Although in your case that would basically just be the number of laps per person.

Comment: Do you know how do this in an Access Query? I need a query that returns the total laps per id

Comment: The second query gives you the total laps per ID. The only thing sql server specific is the datediff function. But it looks like Access has that as well with similar syntax (http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php), try changing the "second" inside that function to just "s".

Comment: I noticed a problem with this query. If multiple timestamps have exactly the same time, they are all counted, but it should only count that once. See example here: sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5cbd/1 only 1 should be counted, but 3 are shown. Do you have any advice on how to correct this? Thank you.

Comment: @user3513237 It is bad design in any table to allow 2 rows to have identical values across all columns. 2 identical timestamps for the same person shouldn't be allowed. You can create a composite primary key on person ID and timestamp to avoid this. This will reject any inserts that would result in a duplicate.

Comment: But what happens is that when a barcode is scanned, it's and timestamp racerID are inserted into the table, so it is possible that the same racerID is scanned more than once within 1 second, giving it the same timestamp.

Comment: @user3513237 I know it's possible but because it would only happen if they accidentally scan it twice I would create a composite primary key on those 2 fields so that whenever it happens the 2nd/3rd/4th etc. scan in the same second doesn't actually get inserted, only the 1st does.

Comment: I don't want any intervention from the user, because I always need the cursor to be on a text box. I just kind of want it to ignore the duplicate entries. Also, what exactly is a composite primary key. Is that where I make 2 fields primary keys?

Comment: Creating a composite primary key doesn't involve any intervention from a user. Yes, a primary key is just a primary key that involves more than one field. The primary key establishes two constraints: unique and not null. Thus, after you create it, if any person or application tries to insert a row that has values the same as those of another row (in the fields defined in the primary key), the database will reject the insertion of that new row. Seeing as you should not have duplicate data and are going to just ignore it anyway, that is why you want to create a composite (2+ fields) primary key.

Comment: Having duplicate data also makes it difficult to uniquely identify a row for purposes of updating or deleting, which is another reason to create a primary key. (a composite primary key in your case, the ID and the timestamp together, as a combination)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge it is impossible to do with just a SQL statement as presented.

I use two approaches:

1. For small result sets, remove the surplus records inside your time windows in code, then calculate the relevant statistics. The main advantage to this approach is you do not have to alter the database structure.
2. Add a field to flag each record relative to the time window, then use code to preprocess your data & fill the indicator. You can now use SQL to aggregate / filter based on the new flag column. If you need to track multiple time windows, you can use multiple flags / multiple columns (e.g. 30 second window, 600 second window, etc)

For this, I'd recommend the second approach, it allows the database (SQL) do more work after you once the preprocessing step is done.